# Create text channel using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that creates a text channel. I tried to look for a solution but it wouldnt work.

Here is the code I have

```
@client.command()
async def create(ctx):
  guild = 841035735011819541
  await guild.create_text_channel('test')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
@client.command()
async def create(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')
```

#200th answer!
[reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5278625/How-do-I-create-a-text-channel-with-discord-py)

Answer (score 1):

`guild` is an integer, integer do not have the `create_text_channel` method. You want to get a `discord.Guild` instance which has the `create_text_channel` method

```py
@client.command()
async def create(ctx):
    guild_id = 841035735011819541
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
    await guild.create_text_channel('test')
```